# External WD drive not recognized

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, data-recovery

I have a friends WD hard drive, he has had it for about 8 years. I know, a long time. After recently picking it up after not using for a while, it seems that it will not recognize on the multiple machines that he's plugged it into. Thats Windows Vista, Windows 7 and windows XP.

Here is the model [Western Digital Passport 120GB USB](http://www.geeks.com/details.asp?invtid=WDXMS1200TN-PB-R)

He has a lot of music on there and he would really like the data off it.

Is there anyway to access the hard drive directories in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser, I edited your question, feel free to revert the changes or edit it again. Have you tried a linux live cd (eg ubuntu)?

Answer (score 0):

Given that it's now out of warranty, I'd recommend getting another enclosure and opening the WD to put the drive in the new enclosure. If that doesn't work then the problem is a bit more serious and difficult (expensive) to solve.